# Loading a DLL in the GAC

Tags: dll, windows-server-2012-r2, global-assembly-cache

currently I have a problem with getting a DLL into the Windows GAC. I tried to follow the steps of creating a DLL and loading it as described in this blog post:
http://blogs.technet.com/b/cloudpfe/archive/2014/02/01/how-to-create-a-custom-authentication-provider-for-active-directory-federation-services-3-0-part-2.aspx

At the point where I try calling the following command:

```
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::Load("System.EnterpriseServices, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7514a164b89fa979")
```

I get an error which tells me that System.EnterpriseServices could not be found:

> Exception calling "Load" with "1" argument(s): "Could not load file or
>   assembly 'System.EnterpriseServices, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=7514a164b89fa979' or one of its dependencies. The
>   system cannot find the file specified."

The specified DLL (System.EnterpriseServices) does exist* on the machine.

So now my question is, why can't this method find the DLL and what do I have to do/change to get this command to work?

NOTE: I Tried this on a vanilla Windows Server 2012 R2 with just ADFS parts installed; And I've called the command from the Powershell.

***UPDATE:** The System.EnterpriseServices DLL resides in 
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_64\System.EnterpriseServices\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a 
and 
C:\Windows\WinSxS\amd64_system.enterpriseservices_b03f5f7f11d50a3a_4.0.9600.1638‌​4_none_53a3f9b13fac0ba5\  
So it should be available from the GAC.

Comment: *Where* does it "exist on the machine"?  Use Fuslogvw.exe to troubleshoot assembly resolution problems.

Comment: It is located in C:\Windows\WinSxS\amd64_system.enterpriseservices_b03f5f7f11d50a3a_4.0.9600.16384_none_53a3f9b13fac0ba5\System.EnterpriseServices.dll Is there a way to get Fuslogvw.exe without installing the complete VisualStudio on the Server or at least a similar tool without that dependency?

Comment: That is not the GAC, it is stored in c:\windows\microsoft.net\assembly.  So the error is entirely normal.  Pretty bizarre to get it in the *unmanaged* side-by-side cache btw, must be a really flaky installer doing this.

Comment: So the System.EnterpriseServices.dll should also be in the GAC directory? Could that mean, that the .Net installation (which as I'm reading comes pre-installed with Win8.1) is corrupt?

Answer (score 1):

I think your public Key token is incorrect, you found your own answer with your update :) .

It should be 
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::Load("System.EnterpriseServices, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=**b03f5f7f11d50a3a**")

Give this a try.